# How to declare array of a particular type in ruby documentor?

Tags: ruby, rubymine, rdoc

I'd like to declare an array of objects with the exact object class in rubydoc  for either a parameter or variable, or for `@return`. (it must be RDoc?..)

The main reason, to make RubyMine (or another IDE) work for autocomplete stuff, clickable methods, refactoring, etc., in right way.

In PHP will look like:

```
/**
 * @param array $items
 * @param Filter[] $filters
 * @return Result[]
 */
function filter($items, $filters) {}
```

I'm just not sure if it can work in similar way in RubyMine:

```
##
# @param [Array] items
# @param [Filter[]] filters
# @return [ResultClass[]]
#
def filter(items, filters); end
```

---

Extra example in PHP:

```
class My
{
    public $name;
}

/**
 * @return My[]
 */
function foo()
{
      // Similar code here
      //return [new My(), new My()];
}

function show()
{
    foreach (foo() as $item) {
        // IDE will make autocomplete for My::$name
        echo "$item->name\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, `@return [Array<My>]` should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class TheClass
  # @param items   [Array]
  # @param filters [Array<Filter>]
  # @return        [Array<TheClass>]
  def filter(items, filters); end
end
```

As documented [YARD Tags](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#return).

Comment: am I right `# @param filters [Filter]` means just `filters == Filter` in your example?

Comment: @Kirby the form is as following: [@param] [function parameter name] [function parameter type]

Comment: And, just to clarify, in `@return` it means `[TheClass.new, TheClass.new, ...]`, doesn't it?

Comment: @Kirby it means array of instances of `TheClass`

Comment: @param name type - it's absolutely clear. I mean in my example filters suppose to an array with Filter objects.

Comment: @AndrewDeineko, ok got it. It's definitely what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @Kirby I misunderstood, if `filters` is an array it should be `@param filters [Array]`. I think you can specify the class of these objects with `@param filters [Array<Filter>]`